# Можно ли поставить полноценный Kali на флешку?

Tags: linux

Очень нужно установить на флешку какой-либо из дистрибутивов Linux, но кроме как Tails и нерабочей Live Kali так и не смог ничего поставить. Можно ли поставить полноценный дистрибутив на флешку и как это сделать?

Comment: Зайдите в YouTube - там полно роликов.

Comment: По установке полноценной ос не нашел. Только Live версии

Comment: https://youtu.be/2gn-jfcaMLM?si=Yh1VWpNSaS7BK0G4